# Cross Platform App (Xamarin.Forms or Native) and Cross Library (Xamarin.Forms) for C# doesn't display in List

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new in c# and I want to develop mobile application using C# Cross-platform Xamarim.Forms template and I install visual studio 2017 community edition.

But, In C# project list Cross-Platform App (Xamarin.Forms or Native) and Cross Library (Xamarin.Forms) doesn't display.

This is screen-shot of vs:-
[image]

and following modules are installed:-
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest update to visual studio 2017.  Currently 15.6.6.  There are some Xamarin Updates. If it still does not show try repairing visual studio 2017

Comment: I've installed latest updated visual studio and problem still exists. I've also tried reinstalling components and repairing of visual studio. I'm still unable to get cross-platform template in my visual studio.